# Don't want animated elements to cause scrollbar to show up

Tags: css

I have some confetti animated with CSS that causes the scrollbar to appear as it falls downward on the page. Is there a way to specify that the confetti shouldn't be scrollable? Currently it's set to position: relative with overflow: visible so it's clearly visible as it falls downward, but I just don't want it to actually extend the scrollable region.

Here's an [example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ws69fza/1/) exhibiting the problem, I don't want the scroll bar to show up and expand as the falling div travels down the DOM.

```css
@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(3000px);
  }
}

.falling-block {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
hello world
<div class="falling-block">
 falling
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a set of code as a minimal reproducible example.  This may help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We need to see the relevant HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to wrap your confetti in a `<div>` and set `overflow: hidden` on it. Building off of the JSFiddle you've provided, it would be something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  hello world
  <div class="falling-block">
    falling
  </div>
</div>

<style>
@keyframes example {
  from {
     transform: translateY(0px);
   }
   to {
     transform: translateY(3000px);
   }
 }
 
.wrapper {
 /* Have the wrapper take up the full height and width of the viewport */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.falling-block {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
</style>
```